# XSL choose when $variable = $variable

Tags: xslt, variables

I'm trying to check if two XSL variables are the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files>
<file filename="export.csv" path="/export" active="true" ftp="false">
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:variable name="quote">"</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="sepstart" select="'&#44;'"/> 

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>"CustomerID"</xsl:text>

<xsl:variable name="second_check">0</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="orders/order">
<xsl:for-each select="items/item">

<xsl:variable name="output">
<xsl:variable name="first_check"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../../increment_id)"/></xsl:variable>

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$first_check = $second_check">

Do something...

</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>

Do something...

<xsl:variable name="second_check"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../../increment_id)"/></xsl:variable>

</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$output" />
<xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>

</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
</file>
</files>
```

However, it's just skipping over both and not outputting anything.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks OK to me. Maybe you need to show us some of the real code.

Comment: Added some real code for you... might help... I jusy can paste it all as I'm generating an export which is HUGE! the headers go on for ages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "re-declare" variables in XSL. When you write

```
<xsl:variable name="second_check">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(../../increment_id)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

That has no affect, because of this

```
<xsl:variable name="second_check">0</xsl:variable>
```

I can't help you though (yet), because I'm not really sure what you're trying to do

Comment: Well you just answered my question I am trying to re-declare my variables with every loop, thats where I'm going wrong. Thanks very much